# Expect mock to receive message in rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, rspec

I'm having trouble setting expectations for a mock used in one of my controllers:

controllers/blark_controller.rb

```
class BlarkController < ApplicationController
  def show
    user = User.first
    user.inspect
    render nothing: true
  end
end
```

spec/controllers/blark_controller_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe BlarkController do
  describe 'GET :show' do

    let(:user) { mock_model User }

    before do
      User.stub(:first).and_return(user)
      get :show
    end

    it 'blarks' do
      expect(user).to receive(:inspect)
    end

  end
end
```

Results in this:

```
22:04:58 - INFO - Running: spec/controllers/blark_controller_spec.rb

BlarkController
  GET :show
    blarks (FAILED - 1)

Failures:

  1) BlarkController GET :show blarks
     Failure/Error: expect(user).to receive(:inspect)
       (Double "User_1001").inspect(any args)
           expected: 1 time with any arguments
           received: 0 times with any arguments
     # ./spec/controllers/blark_controller_spec.rb:14:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.15579 seconds
1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/controllers/blark_controller_spec.rb:13 # BlarkController GET :show blarks
```

**Can I set expectations on mocks in specs?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can, but the way you're doing it is wrong.

You're calling an action (`get :show`) and then after calling it, setting a future expectation (`expect(user).to receive(:inspect)`). Obvious this won't work because you've already called the action, there is no future for this test.

You either need to set the expectation *before* calling the action (switch the order of the statements) or use rspec's recently-added spies feature to set expectations after the fact. This uses `have_received` rather than `receive`.

For more detail: https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/2-14/docs/spies/spy-on-a-stubbed-method-on-a-partial-mock